Proof any region enclosed by a simply connected curve can be bisected by one straight line.
I had this question on a test and wasn't able to finish it in time, but it stuck in my head and I think I came up with a solution for it. Since this is how I remember the question being, the wording might be a little off, sorry :(
Question: Prove that any region enclosed by a closed, simply connected curve can be bisected by one straight line.
Take a closed, simply connected curve $C$ with area $A$. Any closed, simply connected curve can be described by function for an upper and a lower boundary, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively, which each meet at two points; $a$ and $b$, the leftmost and rightmost points, respectively. The area of this region is therefore:
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)-g(x) dx
$$
Now, take the integral from $a$ to $b'$, an arbitrary point between $a$ and $b$.
$$
\int_{a}^{b'}f(x)-g(x)dx
$$
At $b' = a$, the area will be zero. And at $b' = b$, the area will be $A$. Since the integral as a function of $b'$ is continuous, and ranges from $0$ to $A$, by the intermediate value theorem there must be some point $b' = c$ so that
$$
\int_{a}^{c}f(x)-g(x)dx = \frac{A}{2}
$$
We then know from properties of integrals that
$$
\int_{a}^{c}f(x)-g(x)dx + \int_{c}^{b}f(x)-g(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)-g(x)
\\
\frac{A}{2} + \int_{c}^{b}f(x)-g(x)dx = A
\\
\int_{c}^{b}f(x)-g(x)dx = \frac{A}{2}
$$
We have successfully split the region into two parts of equal area. Since we are evaluating the integrals until a certain $x$ value, this means that the boundary will be a straight line at that $x$ value; therefore, we have shown that you can bisect any region bounded by a closed, simply connected curve, with a (vertical) straight line. $\blacksquare$
Are there any errors in this proof, or any sections that seem to be a little unclear?

Your idea to use intermediate value theorem is the right approach but I don’t see why any simple closed curve should be described by two functions this way.

Adding on to Pranay, For example, the perimeter of the bolded E is a simple closed curve, but doesn't split just into an upper and lower boundary.

Can the region be non-convex? If so, it could well be that even line that cuts through it in such a way that half the area is on either side of the line, actually cuts the region into more than two disconnected parts. Is that considered "bisected"?

@CalvinLin I hadn't thought of that - but could you describe the region with more functions (i.e. one for the top and bottom of each of the tines of the E) and then sum the integrals?

@Pranay I thought that it would be the simplest way to take an integral to find the area, without parameterizing the curve

@Aiden Not easily. Bear in mind that the Jordan Curve theorem, which establishes that there is an "interior region" we can talk about, is already non-trivial.  $\quad$ If we could do what you describe, then the Jordan Curve theorem is trivial (via winding number), so that hints that your approach will hit some snags along the way.

Stop worrying about the particular form of the integration. Just move a line across the region, noting that the area on the "left" side of the line raises continuously from $0$ to $A$, and must at some point be $\frac A2$. The only thing that is necessary from the definition of the region is that the area on the left of the line must always be well-defined (and cannot jump discontinuously, but for a bounded region at least, this is impossible).
